# Keeping WebSocket Connection Alive (React.ts pwa APK) App during Sleep Mode

Tags: android, reactjs, push-notification, signalr, react-typescript

I'm working on a **React.ts pwa** project and I generate an **APK** via the Bubblewrap library to have a native application for android devices.

Thus, for this project I implemented the signalR and when I receive an update from the HUB, I update the data in redux and send a notification to the user.

However, when the device goes into sleep mode, I lose the websocket connection.

For this application, I would like to have continuous real-time and be able to notify user. How can I solve this issue ?

```
export const SignalRWrapper = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const userRedux = useAppSelector((state) => state.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(Notification.permission === 'default')
    {
      Notification.requestPermission();
    }

    SignalRConnection.on("tatus", (planningReadDto: PlanningReadDto) => {
        dispatch(updateBooking(planning));
        
        if(Notification.permission === 'granted' && userRedux.user && isMyTruck(planningReadDto.currentStatus, userRedux.user?.habilitations))
        {
          showNotification(planning.name, planningReadDto.currentStatus);
        }
    });


    SignalRConnection.onclose(()=>{
      SignalRConnection.invoke("KeepAlive");
    })

    setInterval(() => {
      SignalRConnection.invoke("KeepAlive");
    }, 3000);

  }, [userRedux.user]);

  function showNotification(name: string, currentStatus : TruckStatus) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
      registration.showNotification(`${name} : Nouveau statut`,{
        body: `${name} passe au statut ${getNameStatus[currentStatus]}`
      })
    })
  }
```